# TFS2015 Release Management Powershell DSC Variable Use

Tags: powershell, release-management, tfs-2015, alm, dsc

I am using TFS2015 Release Management and Powershell DSC to manage the deployment of applications - previously I was using RM2013.

One thing I have noticed is that in RM2013, in my Powershell DSC scripts I was able to access variables such as $applicationPath - which was populated with the TFS Build Drop location, for use in the DSC scripts and MOF creation.

In RM2015 it doesn't appear that this works? I have tried using the variables listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables

However none of these ever seem to be populated?

Is there actually a way of using these RM2015 system & build variables from *within* a PS DSC script now?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the corresponding generated environment variables (for example $env:Build.DefinitionName).

If it not work try more ways such as `$env:Build_DefinitionName` or `$(Build.BuildNumber)` and `$(Build_BuildNumber)`

Just as [the relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables) mentioned:

> Any text input can reference a variable by using the $(variable_name)
>   syntax and will be substituted with the actual value at run-time. All
>   variables are also exported to the environment as upppercase and any .
>   are replaced with _. In scripts you can reference variables via the
>   environment, i.e. %VARIABLE_NAME%, $VARIABLE_NAME, $env:VARIABLE_NAME,
>   depeding on the operating system.

Comment: None of which work, had previously tried all of these from within DSC scripts to no avail. The only thing that appears to have any effect is creating Session variables from within the Powershell Task - although this appears to be fraught with its own set of problems with regards to escaping and variable creation.